# How to get current date and time in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, date

I want to get current date and time in view.

What I have done:

1. Created a new project in Vs 2013 community for asp.net mvc5 (c#)
2. Added an edmx for my database. So it is database first.
3. Added Model-View-Controller for each of my database classes using Add > new scaffolded item.
4. VS created view and controllers for CRUD operations.
5. Now there are two fields in a view, which represents date and time respectively.
6. Earlier VS created simple text boxes, but i added annotations in model so it created Datepicker and TimePicker in a view.
7. What i would like to have is current date and time in both fields.

model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
```

view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

[image: These are date and time picker. i would like to have actual current date and time]

These are date and time picker. i would like to have actual current date and time

What i had tried so far:

use of `@value = @model.returndate = DateTime.Now;`

model.returndate always gives error. i tried to use in controller as well as in view.

using `Viewbag.Date = DateTime.Now;`  and in view `@Value = @Viewbag.Date`  nothing happens.

Comment: yes. yes. just typo here in question.

Comment: You need to set the value in the GET method before you return the model to the view - `model.Date = DataTime.Today; return View(model);` and you need to apply `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]` attribute to the property (note the ISO format)

Comment: this is new for me. model.Date = DataTime.Today; gives an error "the name model does not exist in current context".

Comment: You need to initialize the model first in the GET method - `var model = new YourModel(); model.Date = DateTime.Today; return View(model);` (you should always return an instance of your model to the view

Comment: Note also that `<input type="date" .. />` which is what the `EditorFor()` generates is only supported in Chrome. In IE and FireFox it will just show a normal textbox. Its better to use a jquery datepicker if you want a consistent UI.

Comment: I believe var `model = new Transaction();` is not working because  there is no model as Transaction. As i said VS scafolded and autogenerated code,  the transaction.cs stays under edmx file. so i cannot use it. How to make object of transaction which is under edmx? See here: https://imgur.com/BSeCABM

Comment: You have not even indicated what you model is. What is the name of the model that you have in the view?

Comment: It is autogenerated. From database.

`namespace CashManagement.Controllers
{
    public class TransactionsController : Controller`

Comment: That is the Controller, not the model. What is the model that your have the property `public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }` in? Its that model you need to initialize

Comment: ` public partial class Transaction
    {
        public int TransactionID { get; set; }
        public string Sr_No { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking here and there, i did this to achieve my goal, which was get current date and time in view.

As it is database first approach, i need to find model class, which is under Model.edmx>model.tt>mycalss.cs.

Then i added annotations like Chris Pratt`s answer. That gave me date and time but not date picker.

Now i went to nuget package manage, added jquery UI in the project. Go here: [jQuery Date picker](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/how-to-add-jquery-datepicker-in-mvc/)

It gives me nice looking, mobile friendly date picker with current date.

Answer (score 2):

As you use a `Model` and an `EditorFor` to display your date from the models' property, you should set it before returning the View:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View(new YourModel { Date = DateTime.Now } );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're binding to a model property, the value you want to be there must be either set on the model property or in `ModelState` (composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData` and `ViewBag`).

For your purposes here, the most appropriate way would be to set the value for the model property. You can do that manually as @ken2k suggests, or you can set it up as a default for the property using a custom getter:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
private DateTime? date;
public DateTime Date
{
    get { return date ?? DateTime.Today; }
    set { date = value; }
}

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
private DateTime? time;
public DateTime time
{
    get { return time ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { time = value; }
}
```

Now, these two properties will always be set to either an explicit value or the current date/time.

Note: I used `DateTime.Now` for the time value, but you should be careful with that. Generally, you should use UTC always for time and then convert to/from local as necessary. The chief problem is that local time in ASP.NET is *server-time*, which may or may not be the time the user's operating in or even that your organization is operating in. Especially if you do something like set up a site in Azure or similar to load balance across different countries for higher availability, then local time becomes absolutely meaningless and actually disastrous.

Comment: What is have done is:
in my model

`[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        private DateTime? date;
        public DateTime Date
        {
            get { return date ?? DateTime.Today; }
            set { date = value; }
        }`


in my controller:in Create Action for Get:

`Transaction tr = new Transaction();
            tr.Date = DateTime.Now;`

This give date with time also in same textbox.

`[DataType(DataType.Time)]
private DateTime? time;
public DateTime time
{
    get { return time ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { time = value; }
}`

Throws exception: https://imgur.com/AAe7DiS

Comment: Your EDMX is out of sync with the entity class. You'll need to update your EDMX and/or your database (if the EDMX is generated from that). Or, just throw all the EDMX crap away and use Code First. See: http://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/